# want initialize function get called automatically when object is used

Tags: javascript

I have following piece of code. In this code, I have a class called `func`. Inside `func`, I have 3 functions i.e. `init, func1 and func2`. Then I am calling init function before `return object literal`. So what happens is when I create new instance of this class using `var f = new func()` then it automatically calls the `init` function so I don't have call it manually. So its like constructor in other object oriented languages when a new instance of a class is created then constructor automatically gets called.

Here is the code

```
var func = function () {
    var a, b,
        init = function () {
            a = 1;
            b = 2;
        },

        func1 = function () {

        },

        func2 = function () {

        };

    init();

    return {
        func1: func1,
        func2: func2
    };
};

var f = new func();
```

Now I want to do the exact same thing as above in following scenario. That is I want the `init` function get automatically called whenever I call any function inside `func` object.

```
var func = {
    init: function () {

    },

    func1: function () {

    },

    func2: function () {

    }
}

func.func1();
```

**Is it possible to make init function automatically called whenever I call any function inside func object in above scenario? If yes then How?**

Comment: do you want to call it once or every time?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to store the references of a all the objects in a data structure, like a dictionary, basically every time you call a function you would need to go through the dictionary and see if the object has been used before, if not initialize it.
Other than that I see no way to do it short of having every function call the initializer if a flag in the object is not set.

Answer (score 0):

This works, I don't think I'd recommend doing this though, why not just use a `class`?

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JqwrA/)

```
var func = {
    a:0,
    b:0,
    init: function () {
        this.a = 1;
        this.b = 2;
        console.log('init');
    },

    func1: function () {
        console.log('func1');
        this.init();
        console.log(this.a);
        console.log(this.b)
    },

    func2: function () {
        console.log('func2');
        this.init();
        console.log(this.a);
        console.log(this.b)
    }
}

func.func1();
console.log("func1>" + func.a);
console.log("func1>" + func.b);
func.a = 0;
func.b = 0;
func.func2();
console.log("func2>" + func.a);
console.log("func2>" + func.b);
```

Comment: Would probably be better conditionally checking whether init had been run and just calling it in each function. Still not really worth it considering this kind of functionality would be better served by a class.

Comment: @DavidBarker, That's not what the OP wants. "...whenever I call any function inside func object in above scenario". Therefore it calls `init()`. I would agree with just using a `class` though.

Comment: yeah I see that's what he said but his class example doesn't actually do that... got to love ambiguity.

Comment: @DavidBarker - truely, not only is it ambigious, I don't see why the OP is try to re-invent something that already exists.